# How to build Protobuf on Arduino target using Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, arduino

I am using SAM Board 32 bit ARM Cortex M3 platform in eclipse. I am follwing the protobuf example given on google protobuf website. I created the Arduino project and added the Addressbook.pb.cc, Addressbook.pb.h which were generated from the protoc 3.4.0.

Then tried to build the the project. But i get the follwing error:

```
../../src/AddressbookArduino.cpp:2:28: fatal error: addressbook.pb.h: No such file or directory
#include <addressbook.pb.h>
                        ^
compilation terminated.
makefile:72: recipe for target 'project/src/AddressbookArduino.cpp.o' failed
make: *** [project/src/AddressbookArduino.cpp.o] Error 1
```

what might be the reason for this and how can I resolve it ?

Answer (score -1):

I was also getting the same error. Make sure you do two things properly.

- first, include all the header files in your project and
- second, You have to add the path of the protobuf in the properties of your solution before compiling it. I used Visual studio and it works fine.

Comment: Why are we unnecessarily sending traffic to YouTube?  Seems like the answer itself should the instructions instead of a video